# Is there a method to browse Illustrator swatch libraries easily?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation

I'm using Illustrator CS6 and find that browsing through all the swatch libraries is not very user-friendly. I have to load every library individually.
As the library names are not really helpful (for me at least) it takes some time to find the right one.

Is there a way to browse all the libraries visually without reloading every single one? Any plug-in, web-app or script is welcome, as long as it can give a quick overview of all the available swatch libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Art View for Mac users allows for Quicklook preview of ASE files](https://www.code-line.com/artview/), but I'm still looking for something like this for windows.

For Photoshop the Swatches are in Presets -> Color Swatches
For Illustrator the Swatches are in Presets -> en_US -> Swatches

You can add those folders to your favorite list in Finder and/or Bridge... preview not great but you can see your swatches easily.

I'll keep looking - ASE preview browser should be pretty basic.

If you use Adobe CC... I know Kuler integrates with that but I don't know if included Adobe Swatches are in Kuler on the web without Adobe CC.

Good luck!

Comment: Kuler is also available in CS6 (`Window->Extensions->Kuler`) but unfortunately it's only for the online color palettes, not for the built in ones.

Comment: yeah - this is a great question... or i guess need.  I'd love to have like an app that just finds ase files, lists them on the left and when you click you get the color bars.  I'll keep looking though.